# add button to ribbon for starting a specific workflow

Tags: workflow

i have a list and a workflow on that list.
to start workflow on a list item users have to click 4 times!
1.select item
2.click workflows on ribbion
3.select the workflow(which has only one wf infact)
4. click start button

this process is really annoying.
What i want to achieve is add a button on ribbon to start workflow after an item is selected on the list..
so steps will be only two
1.select item
2.push button on ribbon which start wf..

no idea how to do this,any path to solution will be cool.
thanks

Comment: [Jennifer Mason](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=03eb5002%2Ddb5e%2D4f06%2Dbd2d%2D3b7b00d3de82&ID=56) has a blog post that might be helpful for you to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a component that does it in 2 steps (with an Ok button)

http://spc3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StartWorkflow&referringTitle=Home

You could change that to trigger the workflow OnLoad instead of the button.

http://spc3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/57419#985217

I might actually add it this weekend.

Comment: thanks men,this is what i need,absolutely!
but i don't get why it is so tricky by default,4 clicks for a wf to start!users must have patience :)